# CSS Styles not showing on IE 7

Tags: css, xhtml

I have recently converted a PSD into a website. The site is working perfect in Firefox and Chrome. But when I tested it in IE7, it doesn't work. Not a single style is applied to the website. 
What could be the problem?

Comment: If it doesn't work, something is probably broken that needs to be fixed. It is likely that it will work once the problem is fixed.  Seriously though, this is going to need a *lot* more detail. Have you made sure the style sheets are getting loaded?

Comment: please provide more details, like html & css => or better a fiddle?

Answer (score 2):

View the source of code, is it css file included properly or not.

And check you added document type or not.

give me the link, will check it and let you know the problem and solution.

Answer (score 0):

Some Styles are not working properly in the IE ,add following codes and try(should be add before the  tag)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```